# Detect whether other music is paused in IOS?

Tags: ios, audio

I know that we can detect whether other audio app is playing music by kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying, however,  this property returns the same value even if the other app's music is paused, so my question is, how can i detect whether the other audio stream is paused or playing? Can anybody help me? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

use code like this:

```
    [notificationCenter addObserver: self
                           selector: @selector (handlerPlaybackStateChanged:)
                               name: MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                             object: nil];

    [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
```